Early 2000s horror movie where a guy uses camera flashes to see before he's killed
I'm looking for a horror move I watched in the early 2000s. I think it was pretty recent when I saw it, so it's likely from the early 00s/late 90s.
So the only scene I remember is a guy being stalked by something (I think it was some type of monster rather than a murderer), and he's in some old decrepit room  that's almost pitch black (I think he was in an abandoned building or something like that), and all he has for a light source is an analog camera. He keeps frantically winding it up and taking pictures to activate the flash to see, so you just keep seeing quick flashes of whatever it is that's about to kill him.
I wish I could remember more about the plot or location. I think I would have remembered it being gory, so it's probably PG-13. It was almost certainly American.

Sounds like the camera flash scene in Saw 2004 - Adam's apartment scene

This is a surprisingly active trope. Help us narrow it down. Was the monster(?) afraid of the flash, or was it just to help the person see?  Was it definitely a male with the camera? Did the flash disable the monster in any way?  And, finally, does the monster manage to kill him?

That may be from the movie Saw 2004.

Leigh Whannel tries to find out the mystery guy with his camera flash.
And this guy with mask would be the monster that you think.


Sounds a lot like Joshua Jackson's Shutter. It's from 2008. 
